# Rails Active Model Serializer - Adding nested attributes to 2nd level model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I have three models namely **Invoice**, **InvoiceDetail** and **Product**. 
An **Invoice has many InvoiceDetails** and an **InvoiceDetails belongs to Invoice and Product**

I have serializers defined for all the three models respectively but when I'm fetch invoice, I'm not able to fetch Product attributes.

**Invoice Model :**

```
 class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoiceDetails, inverse_of: :invoice
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoiceDetails
end
```

**InvoiceDetai Model**

```
 class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Serializers**

```
    class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :total_amount, :balance_amount, :created_at
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :invoiceDetails
end

class InvoiceDetailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :quantity, :discount, :subtotal
  belongs_to :product
end

class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :mrp, :sp, :cp, :stocks, :isPublished
  has_one :category
end
```

**When I fetch an Invoice :
The JSON output does not include product attributes.**

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "total_amount": 450,
        "balance_amount": 350,
        "created_at": "2017-06-27T17:02:20.000Z",
        "customer": {
            "id": 4,
            "company_id": 1,
            "name": "vivek",
            "isActive": true,
            "created_at": "2017-06-27T14:35:50.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-06-27T14:35:50.000Z",
            "mobile": 12345678,
            "address": "test",
            "pan_number": null,
            "tin_number": null,
            "party_name": "xyz"
        },
        "invoiceDetails": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "quantity": 1,
                "discount": 0,
                "subtotal": 150
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "quantity": 1,
                "discount": 0,
                "subtotal": 300
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: There is no association between `product` and `invoice_detail` Which could be the reason.

Comment: There is an association between them, invoice_detail belongs to product as well as invoice

Comment: That is not enough! I suggest you read associations!

Comment: I'm not getting your point, how this association is not enough?

Comment: I did tried already adding has_many invoiceDetails to Product model. It did not helped either

Answer (score 0):

AMS doesn't include associations of associations - it only goes 1 level deep. There are ways around this:

- Use `include` in your controllers ([docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option))
- Use a workaround like [this one](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1845#issuecomment-268725267) - I'm currently using it successfully in production

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following initializer to enable recursive association. However, you need to make sure that there is no circular reference.

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.default_includes = '**'
```